Sorting Shapes and sub shapes alphabetically in visio
Sorry I am a little new to this I have an excel document that creates a visio diagram but the order does not come out alphabetically
'Set shape data properties
.CellsU("Prop.Handle").FormulaU = """" & acdEntity.acdHandle & """"
.CellsU("Prop.Level").FormulaU = """" & acdEntity.acdAttribs("LEVEL")

Is there a way I can when setting the properties make them be set alphabetically?
Or is there a code I can write a macro within Visio to select all shapes and sub shapes.
I have written this
Sub textsel()
Dim shp As shape

Set shp = ActiveWindow.Selection.PrimaryItem

If Vshp.Shapes(4).Characters.Text Like "*test*" Then

Sort Key1:=Range("Page-1"), Order1:=xlAscending
End If
End Sub

But when it comes to running it I get an error saying the range is not defined.
Sorry for being a little vague

It could be related to an unqualified Range reference, see this explanation.

You can use Sort Key cell with syntax like:
'Set shape data properties   
.CellsU("Prop.Handle.Sortkey").FormulaU = "2"       
.CellsU("Prop.Level.Sortkey").FormulaU = "1"   


UPD Please try this way

.CellsSRC(visSectionProp, 0, visCustPropsSortKey).FormulaU = "Prop.Row_1.Label"
.CellsSRC(visSectionProp, 1, visCustPropsSortKey).FormulaU = "Prop.Row_2.Label"
.CellsSRC(visSectionProp, 2, visCustPropsSortKey).FormulaU = "Prop.Row_3.Label"

